# Concatenate Text on Pandas Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to concatenate text along a row, then group by the ID

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
data=pd.DataFrame(data={'ID':['1','1','2','2','2','3','3','3','3'],
                    'Text1':['Apple','','','Laptop','','Pens','','Ruler',''],
                    'Text2': ['Bananas','Grape','Mouse','','DVD Player','','Pencils','',''],
                    'Text3':['Cherry','','','Headphones','','','','','Eraser'],
                    'Text4':['Mango','Strawberries','','','Cell phone','','Sticky Notes','','']
                   })

data =data.set_index('ID')

ID  Text1   Text2      Text3      Text4
1   Apple   Bananas    Cherry     Mango
1           Grape                 Strawberries
2           Mouse       
2   Laptop             Headphones   
2           DVD-Player            Cell-phone
3   Pens            
3           Pencils               Sticky Notes
3   Ruler           
3           Eraser
```

My desired operations:

1. Concatenate row-wise first
2. Group by each ID to get a group of words separated by a delimiter

[image: Desired Data Frame]

Any ideas on how to achieve this output?

Comment: This is straightforward, but it's conventional to give example input and output that people can copy and paste.  Embedded images mean that anyone who wants to reproduce your input would have to type it in manually.

Comment: Sorry I missed a key part of your question with my first answer. I'd suggest looking into `groupby`, `apply`, and `join`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using some combination of `DataFrame.groupby`, `DataFrame.apply`, and `str.join`. Based of off what you have provided you could use something like the following. The following is just an example.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

data = pd.DataFrame(data={'ID':['1','1','2','2','2','3','3','3','3'],
                    'Text1':['Apple','','','Laptop','','Pens','','Ruler',''],
                    'Text2': ['Bananas','Grape','Mouse','','DVD Player','','Pencils','',''],
                    'Text3':['Cherry','','','Headphones','','','','','Eraser'],
                    'Text4':['Mango','Strawberries','','','Cell phone','','Sticky Notes','','']
                    })


cols = [x for x in data.columns if re.search("^Text", x)] # list of all columns
                                                          # that start with "Text"

# function to be applied that takes a row and a list of columns 
# to concatenate
def concat_text(row, cols):
    # The real work is done here
    return ";".join([";".join([str(x) for x in y if x]) for y in row[cols].values])

result = data.groupby("ID").apply(concat_text, cols) # groupby and apply
```

Which will leave you with

```
ID
1    Apple;Bananas;Cherry;Mango;Grape;Strawberries
2    Mouse;Laptop;Headphones;DVD Player;Cell phone
3           Pens;Pencils;Sticky Notes;Ruler;Eraser
dtype: object
```